# exclude header from csv in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I got a .csv and I want to load it into a datagridview. I have a button called button1 and I got a datagridview called datagridview1. I click the button and it appears... including the header, which I don't want.

Please:

```
How do I exclude the header from the .csv ?
```

code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class CSV_Reader

    Private Sub CSV_Reader_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\Gaius\Desktop\meepmoop.csv"
        Dim thereader As New StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default)
        Dim colsexpected As Integer = 7
        Dim sline As String = ""
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

        Do
            sline = thereader.ReadLine
            If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Dim words() As String = sline.Split(";")
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add("")
            If words.Length = colsexpected Then
                For ix As Integer = 0 To 6
                    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(ix).Value = words(ix)
                Next
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2).Cells(0).Value = "ERROR"
            End If
        Loop
        thereader.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

meepmoop.csv:

```
alpha;bravo;charlie;delta;echo;foxtrot;golf
1;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop
2;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep
3;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop
4;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep
5;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop
6;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep
7;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop
8;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep
9;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop
10;moop;meep;moop;meep;moop;meep
```

edit:

```
[...]
Dim sline As String = ""
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
Dim line As String = thereader.ReadLine()
If line Is Nothing Then Return

Do
    sline = thereader.ReadLine
[...]
```

The above addition to the code works but I have no idea why. Nor do I understand why I have to -2 rather than -1. I can't rely on guesswork, I'm expected to one day do this professionally. But I just can't wrap my head around it. Explanation welcome.

edit:

```
Do
    sline = thereader.ReadLine
    If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    Dim words() As String = sline.Split(";")
    If words.Count = 7 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(words(0), words(1), words(2), words(3), words(4), words(5), words(6))
    Else
        MsgBox("ERROR - There are " & words.Count & " columns in this row and there must be 7!")
    End If
Loop
```

I've shortened the Loop on the advice of a coworker, taking his word on it being 'better this way'.

Comment: on the first readline...do nothing

Comment: I've tried that with an if statement and a skip and ... i don't know how to skip it. best i had it do was create a top row but not fill it with data.

Comment: The proper thing to do is use Excel interop and read the records. When you do, in your connection string you set `HDR=YES` which informs to exclude the header row...

Comment: set a first time loop variable, to true. check the variable and if true, then do nothing and set variable to false, else do something. basic logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method, using [Enumerable.Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) + [.Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

As noted in *Ondřej* answer, there's a specific tool for these operations: [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
But, if there are no special requirements and the string parsing is straightforward enough, it can be done with the standard tools, as shown in *Tim Schmelter* answer.

This method enumerates the string arrays returned by the [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and groups them in a list that can be then used in different ways. As a raw text source (as in this case) or as a `DataSource`.

```
Dim FileName As String = "C:\Users\Gaius\Desktop\meepmoop.csv"
Dim Delimiter As Char = ";"c
Dim ColsExpected As Integer = 7
If Not File.Exists(FileName) Then Return

Dim Lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(FileName, Encoding.Default)
Dim StringColumns As List(Of String()) =
    Lines.Select(Function(line) Split(line, Delimiter, ColsExpected, CompareMethod.Text)).
          Skip(1).ToList()

DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

'If the DataGridView is empty, add a `[ColsExpected]` number of `Columns`:
DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, ColsExpected).
                      Select(Function(col) New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()).ToArray())

StringColumns.Select(Function(row) DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)).ToList()
```

If you instead want to include and use the Header because your `DataGridView` is empty (it has no predefined Columns), you could use the Header line in the `.csv` file to create the control's `Columns`:

```
'Include the header (no .Skip())
Dim StringColumns As List(Of String()) =
    Lines.Select(Function(line) Split(line, Delimiter, ColsExpected, CompareMethod.Text)).ToList()

'Insert the columns with the .csv header columns description
DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, ColsExpected).
                      Select(Function(col, idx) New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {
                                 .HeaderText = StringColumns(0)(idx)
                             }).ToArray())
'Remove the header line...
StringColumns.RemoveAt(0)
StringColumns.Select(Function(row) DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the header by calling `ReadLine` twice. Also use the `Using`-statement:

```
Using thereader As New StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default)
    Dim colsexpected As Integer = 7
    Dim sline As String = ""

    Dim line As String = thereader.ReadLine() ' header
    if line is Nothing Then  Return

    Do
        sline = thereader.ReadLine()
        If sline Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Dim words() As String = sline.Split(";"c)
        ' ... '
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: my attempts to call readline twice either lead to the first eight rows being skipped or every odd row being skipped. I'm afraid the other thing, the 'using' thing, ... i have no idea how to use that. I've tried adding the remaining code from the top post but it just gives me heaps upon heaps of errors. :(

Comment: @GaiusVulcanusDuodecimus: but i have already posted all code apart from the few lines in the loop which follow `Dim words() As String`

Comment: I put the 'line' snippet in between my sub and that works... but I don't know why.

Comment: @GaiusVulcanusDuodecimus: it works because of the `thereader.ReadLine()` before the loop. This will advance the stream-reader to the next line which is the line after the header. So every `ReadLine` in the loop will now switch to the next data-line(the header is skipped):

Answer (score 0):

You should use VB.NET class that is designed and tested for this purpose. It is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` and you can skip header by calling `ReadFields()` once before you start parsing in loop.